# Displaying an element only once within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Here is the code,

```
<span class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in searchFields.TitleLevel">
    <span ng-show="$first">Title Level:<br /></span>
    <span ng-show="wizardData[item.field]!=false && wizardData[item.field]!=null" class="ui-select-match-item btn btn-default btn-xs frosted" type="button">
        <span class="close ui-select-match-close" ng-click="wizardData[item.field]=false; isItDirty('Contact')">&nbsp;×</span>
        <span>
            <span class="ng-binding ng-scope">{{item.name}}</span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span ng-show="$last"><hr class="col-lg-12 sidenav-separator"/><br /></span>
</span>
```

I want to display "Title Level" only once and when the `ng-show` of `wizardData` is true. The `wizardData` is the list of checkboxes so if I keep "Title Level" under the `ng-show` of `wizardData`, then `$first` condition is only true when the first checkbox is selected otherwise it is false.

Is there a way through which I can display "Title Level" whenever any checkbox is selected?
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would put an ng-click handler on the checkobox, bind that to a function that changes a model on $scope to trigger a $digest. SearchFields.showTitle = true
Then just do ng-show="SearchFileds.showTitle"